# Nested Partials and Object References in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a partial view that looks like:

```
<div ng-if="activeItem.typeOf == 'text'">
     <div onload="item=activeItem" ng-include="'views/app-builder/text.html'"></div>
</div>
```

when the users clicks a button I have a controller method that resets the activeItem

```
 $scope.showDetails = function(item){
        $scope.activeItem = item;
 };
```

with activeItem looking like:

```
{  name: "Candy", typeOf: "text" }
```

it works as expected the first time, but every time after that the active item in the nested partial is never updated.  Likely because the reference `onload` was never updated.  What is the 'right' way to handle this in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use a reference to facilitate AngularJS to track the change via prototype. This is the nature of Javascript. Try this approach:

```
$scope.activeItem = {};
$scope.activeItem.values = {
    name: "Candy0",
    typeOf: "text0"
}

$scope.showDetails = function (item) {
    $scope.activeItem.values = item;
}
```

In the view

```
{{item.values.name}}
```

Comment: Didn't even think of that ... great idea!